# Let $D$ be the open disc centred at $i$ and radius $3$. Prove that $|z-\omega|<6$ for all $z,\omega \in D$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing

I can see why it is less than $6$ because the longest distance is from either side through the origin and it can't be $6$ because it is an open disc.

I think to prove formally I should use the triangle inequality, but I am not sure how to go about doing that. Could someone help me get started with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $z,\omega\in D$,
$$\tag1|z-i|<3$$
and
$$|\omega-i|<3$$
Thus,
$$\tag2|i-\omega|<3$$
By the triangle inequality,
$$|(z-i)+(i-\omega)|<|z-i|+|i-\omega|$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$,
$$|z-i|+|i-\omega|<6$$
Thus
$$|(z-i)+(i-\omega)|=|z-\omega|<6$$

Answer (score 0):

You should begin with
$$|z-w|=|(z-i)+(i-w)|$$

Comment: Then we know (z-i) < 3 and (i-w) < 3, so (z-i)+(i-w) < 6.

Is that enough to prove or is there a more formal approach that I should be taking?

Thank you!

Comment: I hadn't seen that someone else posted the answer! Thank you for leading me in the right direction.